# Java and JavaScript same sha256 hex

Tags: javascript, java, hash, hex, sha256

To get a Java SHA256 hash I use the following method:

```
public String getSha256(String text, String encoding){
    String sha = "";
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        md.update(text.getBytes(encoding));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        sha = new String(digest);
        sha = sha.replace("\n", "");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return sha;
}
```

Like so:

```
String testValue = getSha256("test", "UTF-8");
```

Then to get the HEX value out of it I do the following:

```
public String getHexFromString(String text){
    String hex = "";
    try {
        byte[] myBytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(myBytes);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return hex;
}

System.out.print(getHexFromString(testValue));
```

The result of this is:

```
C5B8E280A0C390EFBFBDCB864C7D65C5A12FC3AAC2A0C3855AC39015C2A3C2BF4F1B2B0BE2809A2CC3915D6C15C2B0C3B008
```

In javascript I do the following (using [this](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) library):

```
var hash = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash("test");
console.log(sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hash));
```

And the result is:

```
9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

**How can I get same hex in Java and Javascript?**

What am I doing wrong, is it the Java or Javascript code?

Comment: `sha = new String(digest);` - don't do this. The digest is arbitrary binary data. You should convert `digest` to hex, rather than converting it into a string and then calling your `getHexFromString` code. That's almost certainly *part* of the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, this solved the issue :) ... also thanks for answering my other questions longer ago, somehow you are the right guy at the right place, ill remember that :P

Answer (score 2):

@JonSkeet was right, changed the method, it now looks like this:

```
public String getSha256Hex(String text, String encoding){
    String shaHex = "";
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        md.update(text.getBytes(encoding));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        shaHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return shaHex;
}
```

And the result is:

```
9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
```

The only difference is that the Java hex is upper case, but thats a minor thing to solve.